# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 259

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read the below comma-separated value (CSV) file. First row has only one field.

[image]

**df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)**

I am getting the below error :

```
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 259
```

I understand that when Pandas reads the first row it finds only one field, so it thinks that all other rows will also have one field.

If I use skiprows=1 like this :

**df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)**

then no error comes, although the first field is skipped. *Surprisingly other rows further down the csv file that again contain **only one field** are  read successfully.*

I cannot use skiprows=1 as I have to read the file in its entirety. Please help me in reading the complete file successfully.

Comment: `Surprisingly other rows further down the csv file that again contain only one field are read successfully.` - panas generate range columns names by first row, here after skip first by second row, so if less values in next row like second row it working well. If more values, e.g. 300 it raise error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no true header line in your file, so `header=None` is correct. But as the first row is shorter than the other rows, you have to give `read_csv` a hint for the actual number of columns. A simple way is to pass a `names` option to give it the names of the columns - BTW it implies a default value of `None` for the `header` parameter. Assuming you have never more than 259 columns, you could use:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', names = [f'col{i+1}' for i in range(259)])
```

Just replace the `259` by the maximum number of columns - it is never an error to declare non existent columns.